# I've gotten an error that says "000 curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 18332: Connection refused"

Tags: bitcoind, client

Macintosh HD>Users>nishidaryu>Library>Application Support>Bitcoin>bitcoin.conf

```
          rpcuser=ryunishida
          rpcpassword=password

          HOST=localhost
          server=1
          txindex=1
          rpcport=18332
          testnet=3
```

---

Then I enter the code below

```
 curl --user ryunishida:password --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:18332/ -w '%{http_code}\n'
```

---

The i got the error.

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 18332: Connection refused

 est=0000000000000000131fad7d9f3e327b229f8307513db4a8b1fa6ee451ab889b
```

height=354966 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.72942 tx=67647897 date='2015-05-04 21:21:14' progress=0.272143 cache=603.4MiB(4479558txo)
 2017-08-21 22:57:46 Pre-allocating up to position 0xa00000 in rev00264.dat
2017-08-21 22:57:46 UpdateTip: new 
 best=00000000000000001615f90d49ca0e1cb869fcd8427f495fa4f0d978e5db473f height=354967 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.729456 tx=67649081 date='2015-05-04 21:27:45' progress=0.272148 cache=603.3MiB(4478757txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:46 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000012f058764064d0153bd74289b17fb6b27350881d8da13cb7 
 height=354968 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.729493 tx=67651444 date='2015-05-04 22:09:58' progress=0.272158 cache=603.6MiB(4480444txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000006d2018e9b9b09bf922b373f81dc58cc4003e4e9a8a432f height=354969 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.72953 tx=67652384 date='2015-
 05-04 22:22:02' progress=0.272161 cache=603.5MiB(4479690txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000033478f661ac741a6dd1ffea71d0eab468ab9aa42f173dff height=354970 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.729567 tx=67653681 date='2015-05-04 22:26:12' progress=0.272167 cache=603.5MiB(4480056txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000f2be95aadbccc1ac9d7d48707087afdb62824f5d1b12eb6 height=354971 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.729604 tx=67654797 date='2015-05-04 22:30:04' progress=0.272171 cache=603.6MiB(4480873txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000ead2a41cbe7181eebabcfa5b2fe6cef7a4aeb6b55dba0cb height=354972 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.729641 tx=67657563 date='2015-05-04 23:10:54' progress=0.272182 cache=603.7MiB(4482027txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000baff238a3586819dbe4dbc1867a1a39f30e930cd9df2bf4 height=354973 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.729677 tx=67658315 date='2015-05-04 23:15:51' progress=0.272185 cache=603.7MiB(4481277txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000f127e1a0ff0569d6d12443abdfd462c8c26df2ae4d15944 height=354974 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.729714 tx=67658985 date='2015-05-04 23:23:16' progress=0.272188 cache=603.6MiB(4481195txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000157ad89daea0378f166da78b2a318020ce91c3fceceafca height=354975 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.729751 tx=67659273 date='2015-05-04 23:26:55' progress=0.272189 cache=603.7MiB(4481258txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000e7f7961db3f1c66f51bc4e02f38bfd38674f2b7553314b3 height=354976 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.729788 tx=67659400 date='2015-05-04 23:27:18' progress=0.272190 cache=603.6MiB(4481156txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000007e3a0824a86b9bfb41eff5a2922023d4412b78d53f7ded9 height=354977 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.729825 tx=67659627 date='2015-05-04 23:30:26' progress=0.272191 cache=603.6MiB(4481105txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000005a51002cb8e60c3d4be68442c53961542d99f8152588b28 height=354978 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.729861 tx=67660082 date='2015-05-04 23:40:13' progress=0.272192 cache=603.6MiB(4481029txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001388f868a4c3064b590539b9b3a04bca84bf8b2b74ba0889 height=354979 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.729898 tx=67661498 date='2015-05-04 23:53:07' progress=0.272198 cache=603.6MiB(4481026txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 Pre-allocating up to position 0xb00000 in rev00264.dat
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000087eddfd1f31bf696779531ad0428f48ccc6b34bd5d9e4f3 height=354980 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.729935 tx=67662569 date='2015-05-05 00:09:16' progress=0.272202 cache=603.7MiB(4481770txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000108c19386547eec79a9aa91f2e6cb581b3aa098c927a7032 height=354981 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.729972 tx=67663090 date='2015-05-05 00:16:51' progress=0.272204 cache=603.7MiB(4482020txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000f490b20c3e59af00e61444bb15bc13cbbf18052fda98cf8 height=354982 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730009 tx=67663368 date='2015-05-05 00:21:12' progress=0.272206 cache=603.8MiB(4482085txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000ac4d6497c11ecd4edd1274b0bcf181658a8d19b73ab3cf3 height=354983 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730046 tx=67663847 date='2015-05-05 00:28:01' progress=0.272208 cache=603.8MiB(4482192txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000728bbf03cc4feb5bdcff5bf8cf74b54e5e2df1d8160f5f6 height=354984 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.730082 tx=67664089 date='2015-05-05 00:31:14' progress=0.272208 cache=603.8MiB(4482253txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000646e2241de38777d1afd577b50de57e5f8fa728833b6474 height=354985 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730119 tx=67664090 date='2015-05-05 00:32:02' progress=0.272208 cache=603.8MiB(4482254txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000005e5a5cb8804c7671aa9423464bc398b5cf20b49078f2773 height=354986 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730156 tx=67664990 date='2015-05-05 00:44:55' progress=0.272212 cache=604.3MiB(4486601txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000a92cf169d8667a6a27cb813dc0fc55335139d6c86545390 height=354987 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.730193 tx=67665061 date='2015-05-05 00:45:33' progress=0.272212 cache=604.3MiB(4486804txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000086260a5d4a3b256093f832f85b3317e35aa901437ddfaaf height=354988 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.73023 tx=67665376 date='2015-05-05 00:50:20' progress=0.272214 cache=604.3MiB(4486959txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000170069f72eb85516ff457fdc342cc127356dd79a9ece0f4c height=354989 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.730266 tx=67665615 date='2015-05-05 00:53:27' progress=0.272215 cache=604.4MiB(4487414txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000007398380f9b977dca33789388f01bbb12fcae1e5432e3b9e height=354990 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.730303 tx=67665882 date='2015-05-05 00:57:00' progress=0.272216 cache=604.5MiB(4487853txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:47 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000cd5669c7f4a84118de23cd06913a3248823eba1228d524 height=354991 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.73034 tx=67666538 date='2015-05-05 01:05:51' progress=0.272218 cache=604.6MiB(4488883txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000013b376160cc763defe8e106e279681290785cd59423dc6c2 height=354992 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730377 tx=67666850 date='2015-05-05 01:09:44' progress=0.272220 cache=604.6MiB(4488646txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001320c8181b11d3f02d6c8701a5170713dbdfa260011830be height=354993 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730414 tx=67667874 date='2015-05-05 01:40:38' progress=0.272224 cache=604.7MiB(4489567txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000e6fb7eb872db8d751f0416716fdbf42758a3dd4df0f9a40 height=354994 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.73045 tx=67669148 date='2015-05-05 01:45:36' progress=0.272229 cache=604.6MiB(4488760txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000066fa7334af0df6dd0e33ae3673ffa430786f61c45bb35e2 height=354995 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730487 tx=67669295 date='2015-05-05 01:47:16' progress=0.272229 cache=604.5MiB(4488565txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000113b62f20455002d0a4f5be3ca10b16bbdf5d638d1dd0be height=354996 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.730524 tx=67669783 date='2015-05-05 01:54:18' progress=0.272231 cache=604.6MiB(4488812txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000c1d6b36cfbcd962a1f32dc504af13118fb983ef4e55944a height=354997 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730561 tx=67670262 date='2015-05-05 02:00:24' progress=0.272233 cache=604.6MiB(4488783txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000080c826f7515aae9a3d18a65472029dbb1343e5d78b685c0 height=354998 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.730597 tx=67670725 date='2015-05-05 02:07:42' progress=0.272235 cache=604.6MiB(4488655txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000032a581d801b0a3d269f7633d0d6cf99158e9074578c22fd height=354999 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730634 tx=67671646 date='2015-05-05 02:21:33' progress=0.272239 cache=604.6MiB(4488941txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000b36c1f926e9f4afeac50a580d220c38aacd0185ffc77126 height=355000 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730671 tx=67671774 date='2015-05-05 02:29:06' progress=0.272239 cache=604.6MiB(4489000txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000149fb3ca841309360d5f648ba1e36d0a891c165dd5f89804 height=355001 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730708 tx=67672597 date='2015-05-05 02:34:52' progress=0.272243 cache=604.6MiB(4489037txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000012cc000d5fde40d9133b99c3248eee9f8fb453ac3e3c9fc5 height=355002 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.730745 tx=67675071 date='2015-05-05 03:30:50' progress=0.272253 cache=604.8MiB(4490406txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000c07f84a68ae35632e5a7bc8c2c3b44fe25ddfbfd080b71b height=355003 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730781 tx=67676270 date='2015-05-05 03:34:04' progress=0.272257 cache=604.7MiB(4490163txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000e7b9baf6a815c05b416b6342962197846eeb298d4602163 height=355004 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730818 tx=67676751 date='2015-05-05 03:36:19' progress=0.272259 cache=604.8MiB(4490704txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000013a15ea6356fd802e862a31d95f26f16176b60a7f9d03358 height=355005 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.730855 tx=67677212 date='2015-05-05 03:43:46' progress=0.272261 cache=604.8MiB(4490646txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 Pre-allocating up to position 0xc00000 in rev00264.dat
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new 
 best=0000000000000000005ceece7a8f247433cce63a4fd6b8ebe7c47f8cc1918730 height=355006 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730892 tx=67678892 
 date='2015-05-05 04:05:52' progress=0.272268 cache=605.3MiB(4494999txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new 
 best=000000000000000013b1f8d2a39ab4f6f5c4079dc9aa5c9ae23b07a45191ffa1 height=355007 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730929 tx=67679522 date='2015-05-05 04:14:11' progress=0.272271 cache=605.4MiB(4495318txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:48 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000c4eae36d98809c24d42bf671978526914495fdee16eba07 height=355008 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.730965 tx=67681734 date='2015-05-05 04:56:48' progress=0.272279 cache=605.5MiB(4496424txo)
   2017-08-21 22:57:49 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000be5e8bebac30df1463241b9ab8669605936e20ee9370a39 height=355009 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731002 tx=67682377 date='2015-05-05 05:01:48' progress=0.272282 cache=605.4MiB(4495316txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:49 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000105cfab9e6cca7cb1822c508e52973f1128d3d83480c05d height=355010 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731039 tx=67682547 date='2015-05-05 05:01:45' progress=0.272283 cache=605.4MiB(4495522txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:49 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000a8db82eff5ec78d3feb4b8699d140fe52accd3be4ba90c6 height=355011 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731076 tx=67683299 date='2015-05-05 05:15:27' progress=0.272286 cache=605.4MiB(4495735txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:49 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000008cf8e3d3295bc3499edc4d256aebd317ef453a9f01a5968 height=355012 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731112 tx=67683476 date='2015-05-05 05:17:20' progress=0.272286 cache=605.4MiB(4495578txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:49 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000f2211a9e252dfaa2f656ba632d1645d8885b54a258d1dfe height=355013 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731149 tx=67683823 date='2015-05-05 05:19:18' progress=0.272288 cache=605.4MiB(4495519txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:49 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000421a8b979ea8cf6cfe5377e6aa88a163a7691055302b602 height=355014 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731186 tx=67684769 date='2015-05-05 05:35:35' progress=0.272292 cache=605.4MiB(4495753txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:49 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000910d42aefde5e09539c05119ab2fadb3053fb71dedc607e height=355015 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731223 tx=67684897 date='2015-05-05 05:48:03' progress=0.272292 cache=605.4MiB(4495645txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:49 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000008ed45f34eca684d9d351bde8d01fd7198bb666adac70a20 height=355016 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.73126 tx=67685277 date='2015-05-05 05:42:02' progress=0.272294 cache=605.4MiB(4495547txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001573d1aa3c756b0e6d62591cf5e1b4360d0a96e39e41ec4c height=355017 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731296 tx=67686335 date='2015-05-05 06:00:59' progress=0.272298 cache=605.4MiB(4495714txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000f76f04a3170243fa978673465cc096b7bd022aacd1296ed height=355018 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731333 tx=67686586 date='2015-05-05 06:17:08' progress=0.272299 cache=605.4MiB(4495605txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000002405ca139a0481f771af3c868bc1bee6fa3d44a3264decc height=355019 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.73137 tx=67688975 date='2015-05-05 06:54:11' progress=0.272309 cache=605.5MiB(4496706txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000002486a6023a2cbc18ffc55f40ace89ced2ebd9143df99fe height=355020 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731407 tx=67689341 date='2015-05-05 07:03:57' progress=0.272310 cache=605.5MiB(4496321txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000100296dd99bb9d2d2e082d94b1650ee74e774e619ecba46e height=355021 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731443 tx=67690231 date='2015-05-05 07:07:17' progress=0.272314 cache=605.5MiB(4496274txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000105f2032ed871e2daba8e1f83f1d69a3a1db7e2eaa38d558 height=355022 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.73148 tx=67690485 date='2015-05-05 07:09:28' progress=0.272315 cache=605.5MiB(4496445txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000449cf51e1e7a5db93a3cf2a27c5333396a2640996a0b0bb height=355023 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731517 tx=67690585 date='2015-05-05 07:10:34' progress=0.272315 cache=605.5MiB(4496422txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000416506049b419f86de8e0e35ebb6a590d3f223d458a0656 height=355024 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731554 tx=67690830 date='2015-05-05 07:15:32' progress=0.272316 cache=605.5MiB(4496459txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000049cdfd6d4074c61d6d61141f4fc929e5c0a813d0b916b55 height=355025 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731591 tx=67690969 date='2015-05-05 07:16:43' progress=0.272317 cache=605.5MiB(4496439txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000004dc867e4541315090329f45ed4dd30e2fd7423a38a72c0e height=355026 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731627 tx=67691153 date='2015-05-05 07:17:33' progress=0.272317 cache=605.5MiB(4496392txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000006ef727e0e4a456d1c53bfbb972100fe6c02aed4129c6af9 height=355027 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731664 tx=67691823 date='2015-05-05 07:32:02' progress=0.272320 cache=605.5MiB(4496283txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000006667c124b0f8e9ea7b9ecc4aaa6949a64dc4aeed278e086 height=355028 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731701 tx=67692524 date='2015-05-05 07:41:01' progress=0.272323 cache=605.5MiB(4496414txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000e39e9dea18f78fb917d2a61fbc3885858acb5736d716045 height=355029 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731738 tx=67692835 date='2015-05-05 07:45:05' progress=0.272324 cache=605.5MiB(4496276txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000af5078aabaa03b5ead6826cfccdf0f46d469d6736a0661b height=355030 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731774 tx=67693051 date='2015-05-05 07:48:19' progress=0.272325 cache=605.5MiB(4496132txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001665b830058098349c5279826b396877517b1cb9c0840722 height=355031 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731811 tx=67693160 date='2015-05-05 07:49:08' progress=0.272325 cache=605.5MiB(4496044txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000c31becd1b32471be94c53256f738adad62acdc4e964ed41 height=355032 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731848 tx=67693797 date='2015-05-05 07:59:35' progress=0.272328 cache=605.5MiB(4496201txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000108fb7a3c21491e04be01fbf8d3d310183bd97e6bddc39c6 height=355033 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731885 tx=67693962 date='2015-05-05 08:02:18' progress=0.272329 cache=605.5MiB(4496142txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000ea900c6f107397862fc1578be6c8b881deca4babbf5b2bc height=355034 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731921 tx=67694201 date='2015-05-05 08:05:27' progress=0.272330 cache=605.5MiB(4496431txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000005e08c949c0e6c9a8df7b351b070f7cba008b475c330aceb height=355035 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.731958 tx=67694620 date='2015-05-05 08:10:33' progress=0.272331 cache=605.5MiB(4496393txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000013202f3d202d82d70d5be9af44b24770989bf8925cbbb4a8 height=355036 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.731995 tx=67695178 date='2015-05-05 08:19:08' progress=0.272334 cache=605.5MiB(4496531txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001359218ce1948a429887b440084b68860924a6cd62fdaf56 height=355037 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732032 tx=67695266 date='2015-05-05 08:20:04' progress=0.272334 cache=605.5MiB(4496568txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000015278af940fad044a10e7af79ac424a7712834344cd26d10 height=355038 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732068 tx=67695502 date='2015-05-05 08:22:56' progress=0.272335 cache=605.5MiB(4496568txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000015ac94a71ceb6d698b012c50303774d93199f580f1ae1042 height=355039 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732105 tx=67695580 date='2015-05-05 08:30:40' progress=0.272335 cache=605.5MiB(4496575txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000321cb05567e72bd2faa5d44f6be4b5692d77c41b367a927 height=355040 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732142 tx=67696944 date='2015-05-05 08:43:41' progress=0.272341 cache=605.6MiB(4497013txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000146a99d54646eb2bf5b7aec676b77f1dee6f9acff162dc81 height=355041 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.732179 tx=67697207 date='2015-05-05 08:46:12' progress=0.272342 cache=605.6MiB(4496986txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 Pre-allocating up to position 0xd00000 in rev00264.dat
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000667ada1e714e88f08b4bea9cf5c5e5c9d9c0d55b10d76f3 height=355042 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732215 tx=67697982 date='2015-05-05 08:56:26' progress=0.272345 cache=605.6MiB(4497106txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000014b1af92a4a6c4c193319589b68455446b8bbd79ccda988a height=355043 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.732252 tx=67698218 date='2015-05-05 08:59:35' progress=0.272346 cache=605.6MiB(4497221txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000cc71648326bc5b088f151aa86511d58eee9d8cafe08b1b6 height=355044 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732289 tx=67699011 date='2015-05-05 09:10:08' progress=0.272349 cache=605.6MiB(4497489txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000122a3578dd80a4c382165474983937a2753f641c746abfec height=355045 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732326 tx=67699832 date='2015-05-05 09:32:36' progress=0.272352 cache=605.7MiB(4497575txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000045fdb433b21fb63d3de6ab2374752bee95c213596d0f22b height=355046 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.732362 tx=67700695 date='2015-05-05 09:33:33' progress=0.272356 cache=605.7MiB(4497771txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000007892ed933ef1af3d534519c5098379a7310a68cd1e3370d height=355047 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732399 tx=67700846 date='2015-05-05 09:35:50' progress=0.272356 cache=605.7MiB(4497788txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000008641293a1de7cbde40b24fc29b5cb79c0582664e53ba97b height=355048 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.732436 tx=67701353 date='2015-05-05 09:41:09' progress=0.272358 cache=605.7MiB(4497948txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000e55d2b84f06836a0a132663ab6af152d4f70ed2563b080b height=355049 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732473 tx=67702830 date='2015-05-05 10:03:18' progress=0.272364 cache=605.8MiB(4498598txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000d97c863738c36c06412463c203265cd826c3281acbd5846 height=355050 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.732509 tx=67703933 date='2015-05-05 10:17:41' progress=0.272369 cache=605.8MiB(4498691txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000b7e790ec6cf63bb94e0354516ab3bb5a9aaa96d7676afa8 height=355051 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732546 tx=67705816 date='2015-05-05 10:46:34' progress=0.272376 cache=606.2MiB(4502183txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000fe801a16676667b6e7e270ef989c27ecbe893767d6c7548 height=355052 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732583 tx=67706394 date='2015-05-05 10:48:23' progress=0.272379 cache=606.2MiB(4502435txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000029a678a6c3b12c451cfc8d18e8a21629afdb81120cc33a8 height=355053 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.73262 tx=67707207 date='2015-05-05 10:56:49' progress=0.272382 cache=606.3MiB(4502540txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000168710c7a956b07f740f4f17cf84ca208588d0f0309dcd51 height=355054 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.732656 tx=67707780 date='2015-05-05 11:06:26' progress=0.272384 cache=606.6MiB(4505559txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000ea0c1a2d5e9c7dd67e3b2c14eabedb478313e878282d7eb height=355055 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732693 tx=67708935 date='2015-05-05 11:19:28' progress=0.272389 cache=606.6MiB(4505675txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:57 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000156f0bf7fa060438edec28357c011fe5dbfe48f5b7dc4f59 height=355056 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.73273 tx=67709460 date='2015-05-05 11:24:26' progress=0.272391 cache=606.7MiB(4505758txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000003b44c2f5db22df08866e704412e0d1704c4e6c383a09c72 height=355057 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.732767 tx=67709888 date='2015-05-05 11:27:51' progress=0.272393 cache=606.7MiB(4505883txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000b4d506ba5bbbdba67d4114ddec6b860fa0b4805bd0a247 height=355058 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.732803 tx=67711307 date='2015-05-05 11:43:11' progress=0.272398 cache=606.7MiB(4506460txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000bc5bd7ddecf861bd1488d7553e5124e89b678c7416cdaf4 height=355059 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.73284 tx=67711873 date='2015-05-05 11:49:19' progress=0.272401 cache=606.8MiB(4506882txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000002a24f166c603b798d3fac08a3a6476fefa79dd5f84a555c height=355060 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.732877 tx=67712898 date='2015-05-05 12:00:32' progress=0.272405 cache=606.8MiB(4506644txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 Pre-allocating up to position 0xe00000 in rev00264.dat
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000015904c5a1ab19652278f0d69eb5ed9fc96c30ce8bc326d43 height=355061 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.732914 tx=67714559 date='2015-05-05 12:21:51' progress=0.272411 cache=606.8MiB(4507324txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000021eee625490f82894fd4753229735435a28fb2b0b6698b3 height=355062 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.73295 tx=67714819 date='2015-05-05 12:23:10' progress=0.272413 cache=606.8MiB(4507177txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000bd568195c703df04cd8c5b3d00153c74523a92601aaa4ca height=355063 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.732987 tx=67717005 date='2015-05-05 12:57:34' progress=0.272421 cache=607.0MiB(4508326txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000ceb5b981a3dc1324bd02c90631c1a37d09e6bd59a6d364a height=355064 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.733024 tx=67717940 date='2015-05-05 13:01:10' progress=0.272425 cache=607.0MiB(4508462txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001324d4cb385458edcba6bd65288e04d0aa7ea18e7f558d4f height=355065 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.73306 tx=67719107 date='2015-05-05 13:14:09' progress=0.272430 cache=607.1MiB(4509061txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000b34cfbb72c0db704e7fa3b2bafe8bdbaea9d7f56980cc6d height=355066 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.733097 tx=67719665 date='2015-05-05 13:19:27' progress=0.272432 cache=607.1MiB(4509177txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000004597ff3dabc9ad3e251a0123ae17e9fe002c2fb94333b28 height=355067 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.733134 tx=67720290 date='2015-05-05 13:25:55' progress=0.272435 cache=607.1MiB(4509467txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000001b47a82c40042a20380f73c7070b244c9d2b5dd429b6b9 height=355068 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.733171 tx=67720403 date='2015-05-05 13:26:40' progress=0.272435 cache=607.1MiB(4509595txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001651ad6fc25a5ff1f28244de888efd8c7dd557a76dd96abe height=355069 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.733207 tx=67720642 date='2015-05-05 13:28:20' progress=0.272436 cache=607.1MiB(4509534txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:58 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000708d3f75ed2c56e99e0237547a8012539ae6baad76fe791 height=355070 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.733244 tx=67720809 date='2015-05-05 13:29:54' progress=0.272437 cache=607.2MiB(4510028txo)
2017-08-21 22:57:59 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000659c1295857f37d035074c53cafac35c8769676e58e2e9 height=355071 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.733281 tx=67721712 date='2015-05-05 13:37:56' progress=0.272440 cache=607.3MiB(4511046txo)
2017-08-21 22:58:00 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000152a5befb704571d023b3e74421359309bc6920778e76195 height=355072 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.733318 tx=67722207 date='2015-05-05 13:41:30' progress=0.272442 cache=607.3MiB(4510801txo)
2017-08-21 22:58:00 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000012b422a2d3a33da9700f095f37768709f9973d612f35af83 height=355073 version=0x00000003 log2_work=82.733354 tx=67722208 date='2015-05-05 13:42:25' progress=0.272442 cache=607.3MiB(4510802txo)
2017-08-21 22:58:00 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000a5d047d643ef63b2e5608eecbe4866184f89ce34fce5b4f height=355074 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.733391 tx=67722956 date='2015-05-05 13:51:33' progress=0.272445 cache=607.3MiB(4510960txo)
2017-08-21 22:58:00 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000011ab450f3abe89a18f4911f48bdcd2fc2bb0104721a3d061 height=355075 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.733428 tx=67723200 date='2015-05-05 13:54:24' progress=0.272446 cache=607.3MiB(4510978txo)
2017-08-21 22:58:00 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000001af82cf103fef247f5606ae62deb3630d76003fe10fb5fa height=355076 version=0x00000002 log2_work=82.733464 tx=67724096 date='2015-05-05 14:04:52' progress=0.272450 cache=607.3MiB(4511299txo)
2017-08-21 22:58:00 UpdateTip: new best=000925 tx=67838825 date='2015-05-06 14:55:54' progress=0.272911 cache=612.8MiB(4555745txo)
2017-08-21 22:59:11 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000007da0160fe28a5ad6c0416bbff7f440323be3f948c648764 height=355226

---

lsof -i

Comment: What happens if you use curl with `--verbose`? Also, `HOST=localhost` isn't doing anything; that is not a valid bitcoin.conf option. I don't think `testnet=3` does anything either; the proper config for that is `testnet=1`. You aren't specifying which testnet to use; you are specifying whether to use testnet or not.

Comment: Did you mean I need to specify testnet=1 for config if I use  Testnet? And I don't know about the curl 'cause I was told that I entered the curl to check my bitcoind environment is fine or not by a developer on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, you need to specify `testnet=1` in your bitcoin.conf to use testnet. For curl, use the `--verbose` option after the `curl` command, so your command should be something like `curl --verbose --user ryunishida:password --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:18332/ -w '%{http_code}\n'`. Also, what is `%{http_code}`?

Comment: Sorry I don't know but maybe thanks to specifying that,I can know the status code like 403.im not familiar with curl.

Comment: I got the same error again.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 18332 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 18332: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 18332: Connection refused

Comment: Of course you get the same error, `--verbose` is not a fix, it is a thing to get more information about the error. Can you edit your post with the output of `lsof -i`? This is not going to fix any problems, it will just give us more information to figure out what is wrong. Can you also edit your post with the entirety of the debug.log file which you can find in the same folder as the bitcoin.conf file.

Comment: Sorry the debug.log was too huge so i won't be able to show you all of them.So I posted recent datas.

Comment: The section you posted is not helpful. Please find a section that has 10 blank lines before actual entries. Such sections are for starting up Bitcoin Core which is will have the information I need to see. Please post as much as you can in the entries following those 10 blank lines. If you can't find such a section, just post as much as you can.

Comment: You meant both of them or debug.log or lsof- i?

Comment: Post both the debug.log file and lsof -i output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin Core is not binding to port 18332. Add the following line to your bitcoin.conf file.

```
rpcbind=127.0.0.1:18332
```

Comment: I had that {"result":null,"error":{"code":-28,"message":"Loading block index..."},"id":"curltext"}

Comment: That means that it is working. Bitcoin Core is still in its startup phase. Just wait a few minutes and try again.

Comment: I reinstalled then I got

*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 18332 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'ryunishida'
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:18332
> Authorization: Basic cnl1bmlzaGlkYTpwYXNzd29yZA==
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> content-type: text/plain;
> Content-Length: 71
>

Comment: * upload completely sent off: 71 out of 71 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Tue, 22 Aug 2017 09:29:09 GMT
< Content-Length: 626
<

Comment: {"result":{"deprecation-warning":"WARNING: getinfo is deprecated and will be fully removed in 0.16. Projects should transition to using getblockchaininfo, getnetworkinfo, and getwalletinfo before upgrading to 0.16","version":159900,"protocolversion":70015,"walletversion":139900,"balance":0.00000000,"blocks":149215,"timeoffset":-2,"connections":7,"proxy":"

Comment: ","difficulty":1,"testnet":true,"keypoololdest":1503393418,"keypoolsize":2000,"paytxfee":0.00000000,"relayfee":0.00001000,"errors":"This is a pre-release test build - use at your own risk - do not use for mining or merchant applications"},"error":null,"id":"curltest"}
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
200

Comment: Those responses mean that it is working now.